# Deriving examples of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a problem where we know a solution to a R2 linear system, we were told something about the general solution involving a linear combination of the x and y coordinates?, but I'm a little stuck

Example:  Give an example of a linear system for which (x,y) = (e^(−t) , α) is a solution for every constant α. Sketch the direction field for this system. What is the
general solution of this system?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have a lot of trouble understanding your question. What do you mean by "a linear combination of the x and y coordinates"? What is "(e−t , α)"? I'm lost

Comment: Edited, that is a vector

Comment: Can you take the derivative and relate $(x’,y’)$ to $(x,y)$?

Comment: so like (e^(-t), 0)?  Then I would as a possible matrix A relating the two get ((-1, 0), (0, 0)).